# Show that it is possible to exchange the elements in the norm of a product

Tags: normed-spaces

For $A\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n},B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and  $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$,  is it possible to proof that $\|ABx\|\leq \|B\|\|Ax\|$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true, regardless of which matrix norm you are using.

Let $A,B : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be linear maps defined as:

$$A(x,y) = (x,0)$$
$$B(x,y) = (y,x)$$

Their respective matrices are $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

We have

$$\|AB(0,1)\| = \|A(1,0)\| = \|(1,0)\| = 1$$

but $$\|B\|\|A(0,1)\| = \|B\|\|0\| = 0$$

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what your matrix norm is, but I think the answer is "no". Take A= [[100,0],[0,1]] B = [[0,1],[1,0]], x = [0,1]. Then ABx = [100,0] but Ax = [0,1].